# How to add to php get home url to make links to new pages?

Tags: php, html, web

I'm currently working on a website that's hosted on our development server, I want to make some links that won't break when I move the site onto the new domain, so I plan to use  to first get the root url, but how can I use that to make a link to the page at www.domain.com/blog?

Thanks a lot, hope that makes sense, couldn't really find a better way to word it!

Thanks,
Ethan

Comment: you does when it's possible use the relative url that's mean whitout the www.domaine.com

Like this : **/blog** Or you can have a define variable with the values of your domain and use it when you make a link with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use relative paths or `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`
For example :

```
$baseUrl = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$myLink = $baseUrl."/mypage";
```

Answer (score 0):

Define in a common script like db.php / config.php

```
$application = 'local';
//$application = 'web';

if($application == 'local'){
    define("SITEROOT","localhost/domain.com/");
    $websitelink = "http://".constant("SITEROOT");
}
if($application == 'web'){
    define("SITEROOT","www.domain.com/");
    $websitelink = "http://".constant("SITEROOT");
}
```

Now in your menubar or where you want to add link to any page..e.g. for blog..

```
<a href="<?php echo $websitelink;?>blog">Go To Blog</a>
<a href="<?php echo $websitelink;?>forum">Go To Forum</a>
<a href="<?php echo $websitelink;?>aboutus.php">About Us</a>
```

When you go online , simply disable `$application = 'local'` and comment out `$application='web'` like below

```
//$application = 'local';
$application = 'web';
```

With this approach, you can define many parameters and can use them anywhere in website....Just changing `$application` does the trick...